# PHP code comes as plain text - Ubuntu Linux 22.04.1

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu Linux 22.04.1

I try to execute php code but it's coming up on screen as text instead of rendering output.

I've created a info.php file and putted `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it but it's coming up as text instead of php information.

`php -v` command is giving this output:

```
PHP 8.1.11 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2022 22:29:14) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.11, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Even I checked modules by `php -m` command:

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

can someone help to fix issue?

Comment: How do you execute that php code? Usually it is `php filename.php` in the command line. And we usually configure a web server when trying to execute php in a webpage.

Comment: If you're loading your test code through a web server (Apache, Nginx, whatever), you need to configure such web server to process scripts with the PHP interpreter, and it won't use the CLI binary anyway.